# Sonar Server in Debug Modus - Do not stop at Breakpoint

Tags: remote-debugging, sonarqube-4.5

For the development of my own sonar plugin i want to be able to debug.
after quite a while I found out how to run the sonarqube server in debug mode. Therefore I followed the instruction of the following website. [enter link description here](https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx/wiki/Build-the-plugin#debug)

When I started the server in debug modus an connect eclipse by using the debug configuration, the server starts but it do not not stop at the breakpoints that I have been set. I have set breakpoints to extension point (classes) like the one which extends the SonarPlugin class or the one which extends the RuleRepository class. The logs of these classes are part of the server log file, so I'm pretty sure that this classes are executed. Nevertheless it doesn't stop at the breakpoints.

Anyone ideas whats the problem?

Comment: That are the lines which i put into the wrapper.conf of the Sonar server to start it in debug modus: wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
wrapper.java.additional.3=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

The server runs as three process - a parent application, the web server and a search server. Plugins are loaded into the web server so you need to start this with debug arguments. The options for this seem to have changed and are not yet reflected in the documentation. To debug the web server put:

```
sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,server=y,address=9001
```

into your sonar.peroperties file and start sonar using the StartSonar script. This will launch all three applications, but with the web server suspended. Attach your debugger to port 9001 and you should find your plugin main class and rules definition breakpoints are hit.